# change wordpress Permalink for a single costum post

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

i am using wordpress with the Permalinks structure:

```
http://www.example.com/article/
```

is it possible to have the url with the id for a single costum post?

something like this : `http://www.example.com/postid=1234`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post ID based permalinks always work on all posts and pages and will simply redirect you to the permalink version.

> ## Default: "Ugly"
>
> The default looks like
>
> `http://example.com/?p=N`
>
> where N is the Post ID number. It works on all server environments, but it doesn't look as nice as some of the other options.

From: [Using Permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: yes... i just need my costum post to work like the default and the rest like it is...

Answer (score 0):

Use This
In condition you have to give which post type you are using

```
function append_query_string( $url, $post ) {
  if ( 'product' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {

    return  $url."?postid=$post->ID" ;
  }
  return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: i get : http://www.example.com/?history=galp?postid=12581 and returns a 404... it would be great if  it worked like http://www.example.com/history?postid=12581

Comment: You have to select Settings -> Permalinks -> Post name  and then right this code in the function.php file so, it will works for you.